# How to change computer name so terminal displays it in OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, dns

I have a Mac Server 3.1.2, w/ system 10.9.4 that is not being used as DNS Server. Windows Server 2012 is DNS & DHCP server. On the Mac, Terminal cannot ping hostname of mac, however, it does identify itself with it's hostname so I'm concluding this mismatch is the cause of my issues.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo scutil --set HostName your-hostname
```

Comment: thanks, however, after setting hostname using the command line above, when I try to ping it cannot resolve.